# Remove Update Notification (for all users except ADMIN)

Tags: notifications

I have 2 administrators in my wordpress, but I only want that one of them see the "Update Notification". I've inserted this code on my funtions.php file  and change name of one of my adminastrator login name the code - if ($user_login !== "miguel") - but it didnt' work?

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

this works fine for a specific user login:

```
 global $user_login;
   get_currentuserinfo();
   if ($user_login !== "admin") { // change admin to the username that gets the updates
    add_action( 'init', create_function( '$a', "remove_action( 'init', 'wp_version_check' );" ), 2 );
    add_filter( 'pre_option_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );
   }
```

and this for a specific user id:

```
global $user_ID;
   get_currentuserinfo();
   if ($user_ID !== 1) { // change 1 to the id number that gets the updates
    add_action( 'init', create_function( '$a', "remove_action( 'init', 'wp_version_check' );" ), 2 );
    add_filter( 'pre_option_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );
   }
```

Comment: Hi Bainternet, Thanks I tried also with the ID but still not working? I dont know if this is because I also installed on line of code to hide some wp menus?  <?php
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_menus');
function hide_menus() {
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
If($current_user->user_login != 'admin') {
?>
<style>
#menu-plugins{
display:none;
}
#menu-appearance{
display:none;
}
#menu-settings{
display:none;
}
#menu-links{
display:none;
}
#menu-users{
display:none;
}
#menu-tools{
display:none;
}

</style>
<?php
}
}?>

Comment: Glad i could help.

Comment: Do you think this is a problem?

Comment: I've just tried with your code and it still works so that's not it.

Comment: I'm new to this... Do you think is the palce where I insert the code on funtions.php ( locate on:/wp-content/themes/mytheme/funtions.php)?

Comment: When we talk about this "Update Notification". We are talking about that yellow line that appear on the top?<br>I'm using the wordpress 3.1.2 portuguese version.

Comment: @Miguel yes: I just placed the code to the theme's functions.php and it hid the yellow WordPress update notification bar. (Using v3.1.3 fi-FI)

Comment: DONT USE THIS FUNCTION! it has security flaws...

Answer (score 2):

this seems to work for me:

```
add_action('admin_head', function() {
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options')){
        remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag',      3  );
        remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'maintenance_nag', 10 );
    }
});
```